# how do I store a day-of-week and time-of-day in objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how do I store a day-of-week and time-of-day in objective-c?

i.e. the equivalent of WED's at 7.30pm for example

Is there one specific objective-c object that would do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448021/storing-selected-days-of-the-week-in-an-objective-c-object/5448029#5448029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSDateComponents would be a good start, but an instance of NSDateComponents only makes sense in the context of a particular NSCalendar instance, so you'll want to look into that class, too. Those classes are used together to construct (and deconstruct) NSDate objects.

Comment: ok - I see what you mean - just keep a copy of the NSDAteComponents variable and when you need to apply it you take your date instance in question and apply NSDateComponents to it correct?

Comment: Right. You could apply it to the current date, or to every week of the year, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't NSDate work for your case?

It's the ObjectiveC answer to all problems related to date/time manipulation. Check the documentation, you should either find a method/constructor/... suitable for your case or use NSDateFormatter, for NSString<->NSDate conversions.

Comment: I don't think so - at least not simplistically

Comment: Well, really, it depends on what you're trying to achieve.