# storing selected days of the week in an objective-c object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a particular Objective-C object that could be used to store the selected days of the week?

e.g. SUN, MON, THUR, as a selection for example

EDIT: So asking is there a specific single NS object that would do this, as opposed to having to create one's own array to store.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I store a day-of-week and time-of-day in objective-c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448001/how-do-i-store-a-day-of-week-and-time-of-day-in-objective-c)

Comment: quite different questions I think Caleb - at least as far as I can see

Comment: Other question is: "How do I store a day of the week". Here you're asking how to store several days of the week. Once you know how to store one, storing several is just like storing several of anything else in Cocoa: use a collection class like NSArray or NSSet. So to answer your question directly, no, there's not a class specifically dedicated to storing multiple groups of calendar components.

Comment: thanks - that's what I've been looking for and didn't know whether there might be some class hidden away somewhere

Comment: thanks - that's what I've been looking for and didn't know whether there might be some class hidden away somewhere  - if you want stick in the answer, otherwise I will later on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, no, there's not a class specifically dedicated to storing multiple groups of calendar components.

Answer (score 0):

[NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with [NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s?

Comment: thanks - I guess I was wondering if they was a way to capture this in an existing single NS object (as opposed to have to create your own array)